# Stop bash script with any key

Tags: bash, shell-script, scripting

I'm writing a custom gnome-terminal profile which I want to stop with any key I choose. After pressing the key, my intention is to complete all my commands at that moment and start su. I've tried adding a & to my command,but it didn't work. I'm attaching some info:

**MY CODE:**

```
su --command 'read -n 1 -s key; if [ "$key" == "g" ]; then su; fi;'
echo -n "W" 
sleep 0.09
echo -n "e" 
sleep 0.09
echo -n "l"
sleep 0.09
echo -n "c"
sleep 0.09
echo -n "o"
sleep 0.09 
echo -n "m"
sleep 0.09 
echo -n "e"  
sleep 0.09
```

**EXPECTED RESULT:**

[characters being echoed properly until...]

[key pressed]

```
Welcome

root@myuser:~#
```

Comment: In your script, the `su` is sort of redundant. Just drop to shell with `/bin/sh -l` or similar.

Comment: Allright, I updated my answer, it is as close to complete as I could get with only bash, but it does what you asked.

Comment: Oh nevermind, with a bit more work I managed to get it exactly the way you wanted.

Comment: @Otheus I use `su -c` because my intention is to create a modified gnome-terminal profile that displays a message every time somebody uses it.

Comment: I don't get it. But why do another `su`? Dont you just want to drop into the shell?

Comment: what is a "custom terminal profile"?

Comment: I have to use `su -c` unless I want to get an error as a return. The `then su` command is for dropping into the shell itself; my user.

Comment: In Gnome Terminal, you can create a file with some commands you want to run at startup of the program. You can write lots of this files with several options, which are called 'profiles'.

Answer (score 1):

The closest I could ever get with a similar issue was something like this...

First create a script named inputproc:

```
read -n1
```

Then create a script called mainscript:

```
array=(W e l c o m e)
buf=0
while pgrep "inputproc" > /dev/null; do
    echo -n ${array[buf]}
    ((buf++))
    sleep 0.09
done
#Insert any commands you want to run afterwards here...
```

Then execute them with this command

```
./mainscript & ./inputproc
```

And well, this does exactly what you wanted. I couldn't find a way of doing it with just one script, but amazingly enough, I found a way to do it with just one terminal window.

Besides the obvious (using a while loop to check if **inputproc** is running before each echo command, and using an array to echo the desired letters in order) this works by running **mainscript** in the background while running **inputproc** in the foreground. It is not without flaws, but it's the closest you can get to your desired result I believe.

Comment: That's not what I'm looking for, as I don't want any prompt to appear in my screen. I just want to press a key in order to display the whole message.

Comment: @xvlaze Oh I see, that's quite troublesome, I recall doing something similar in the past though, let me look it up.

Comment: @xvlaze Found a way to do it, surprisingly enough.

Comment: couldn't you put mainscript into a function and have that function invoked within inputproc with job control?

Comment: @Otheus I don't know, never tried anything like that.

Comment: @Cestarian That's quite an impressive job. I'm still starting with programming and I wouldn't have come up with that solution with my current experience. Is there any way to 'hide' the `[1] 3229` number from the screen, as I want to make it as cleaner as possible? After all, this seems to work quite well.

Comment: @xvlaze I don't know, this text signifies the process ID I believe. Look here: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/40102/bash-disable-new-process-pid-message

Also If you're satisfied, please accept the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't work on a lot of levels. Chiefly, bash isn't really good for multi-threaded programming. But if you're going to do it this way, you have to realize two things: (1) in order for your key-read "thread" to work, it has to have exclusive access to the tty. (2) When you put a process in the background, it will naturally copy stdin from the current process' tty. (3) Usually the shell will detect this and stop the background process.

> Only foreground processes are allowed to read from or, if the user so specifies with stty tostop,  write  to  the  terminal.  Background  processes  which attempt  to  read  from  (write to when stty tostop is in effect) the terminal are sent a SIGTTIN (SIGTTOU) signal by the kernel's terminal driver, which, unless caught, suspends the process.

You can see that here:

```
otheus@otheus-VirtualBox ~ $ ( while true; read x; do echo $x; done; ) &
[1] 2841
otheus@otheus-VirtualBox ~ $ 

[1]+  Stopped                 ( while true; read x; do
    echo $x;
done )
```

So the tty-reading process should be in the foreground. The background can do the "work", but make sure you close stdin first: `<&-`

To stop the "worker" process, you will have to know its pid. To do that, you need to enable job-control within a script (it's off by default). `set -m` does this. Start it and kill `%-` after the keypress. You may want to make sure the keypress loop ends when the worker does. You do your key-monitor thread:

```
start_worker &

while jobs %- &>/dev/null; do 
   read -n 1 -s -t 1 key
   # test key
   if [[ $key == q ]]; then
      kill -1 %-
      break
   fi
fi
wait
```

The while condition tests if the job is still running/recognized. Once it ends, jobs will return false, and the loop exits. The read command now additionally times out after 1 second. Finally, after the loop exits, do a wait to make sure the job is "cleaned up". (If you have other jobs running, that will hang here.)

The other thing is: what you're trying to accomplish is inherently dangerous. **Mixing root access and bash scripting is dangerous**. There are some topics to address here, such as what happens when the user hits Control-C or Ctl-Z.

Lastly, I'm not even sure you can mix the worker thread with `su` as in your example. When su runs, it will change the current tty to root, preventing your worker thread from outputting to it.

Comment: I can't implement this to my code as I'm trying to create a custom terminal profile, and I have to write some commands after a `su -c`. I'm also forced to use root because I'm working from a Live USB unit.

Comment: @xvlaze I don't get it. What's a custom terminal profile? Why root? Don't most live usbs have a generic non root login?

Comment: I think this will explain itself better than I do: https://help.gnome.org/users/gnome-terminal/stable/pref-profiles.html.en I'm using Kali Linux Live, which forces me to use root user every time. I've never had the possibility to run it as a standard user, don't ask me why. Anyway, I'm OK with it, as I have got used to it.

Comment: So you want to be able to interrupt the custom profile setup?

Comment: I want to interrupt my own custom command list (the echoes), yes. Whenever I press a key, I want the message to be displayed completely and invoke `su`

Comment: Why invoke su? You're already running a terminal with root privileges? Can we put the whole command in a script, including the echoes? What happens if you don't interrupt the command list?

Comment: I invoke su just because if I don't, terminal will start with just a `#`, and not with `root@kali#~`, not letting me use some commands. If I don't invoke `su` after the echoes, it will just return to the `#` I had.

Comment: At least do `exec su ` to eliminate the intermediate shell.  I must admit, I still don't know what you're really trying to do. Is your custom-terminal-profile saved on the USB ? Are you ultimately trying to do more than just run a few echo commands? Will this profile launch for _every_ terminal you open? Or just the first one? Can you put your profile "Commands" within a script and spawn the script from a controlling program (which in turn is the one passed to gnome-terminal -e)?